# Is there a good, developed typescript library for data structures and algorithms (similar to C++ STL)

Tags: algorithms, data-structure, typescript

I am building a backend server application in nest.js (A progressive node.js library).
nest.js uses typescript, and I need to implement some sophisticated algorithms in the server.
Instead of coding from scratch, if there is a pre-built library for things like binary search trees, etc, it will be very helpful.

I want something like C++ containers, iterators, and algorithms. Something that encapsulates complex data structures and algorithms.

Comment: What algorithms do you need from such a library. Please be specific about what features are you expecting. In its current form, many libraries could be "good" candidates.

Comment: I am currently planning to implement an LRU cache algorithm. But I wish to do a lot more in the future. So i expect a library like C++ STL to provide the required encapsulation for all my needs.